# serach for an element in an array using jQuery.inArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to use jQuery.inArray() method to look for an item in this array. But it works juste when using it to look for a simple word Like "Hello" or "how" in the array below. I want also to have results when looking for "Help" or "me" alone or even "()" but I don't know how ?

```
Array
(
            [0] => Hello
            [1] => Help me please
            [2] => I am stucked
            [3] => I don't know
            [4] => how 
            [5] => to use
            [6] => jQuery.inArray()
            [7] => method
            [8] => Help
            [9] => Thank you
)
```

Comment: please show the source code of the things you have tried that are not working

Comment: if(jQuery.inArray(texto, tab) != -1) 
        {
          // code                                      
        }

Answer (score 0):

For each entry in the array check if the value contains the searched term.

```
$.each(arr, function(k, v){
    if (v.indexOf("SearchWord") >= 0){
     alert(k);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by using the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function :

```
// Define your array
var array = ['Hello','Help me please','I am stucked','I don\'t know','how ','to use','jQuery.inArray()','method','Help','Thank you'];

// Define your search term
var search = 'Help';

// Find results that match (This would return ['Help me please','Help']
var matches = array.filter(function(x){ return x.indexOf(search) >= 0;});
```

Likewise, if you wanted to ignore casing, you could simply use the [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) function on your existing string and your search term :

```
array.filter(function(x){ return x.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0;});
```

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/heduqe/edit?js,output).